# Getting Exception on unittest from method only if test is in ordertest

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

This is line of code where he drop exception.

```
Public Sub Test()     
    ConnectionServices.clientPay.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None
```

If i play only that test, separated from others, he pass, if i set him in order test got exception

Comment: the setup() before this test is different, if you have one

Comment: it doesn't matter. I have 30 of them in order test. He pass if he is first, if he is second, 10th, 20th, he drop exception.

Comment: It is beyond my skill sets, I will push your question up, see what others will say.